# Updating a one-to-one relationship doesn't save in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using the entity framework, I have constructed a one-to-one relationship between class A and class B (shortened for brevity).

```
class A
{
    // Some other stuff

    // Relationship to class B
    public B B { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    // Some other stuff

    // Relationship to class A
    [Required]
    public A A { get; set; }
}
```

When I call a specific entity of class A from the context that I have created, I want to give it a reference to a new instance of class B:

```
// Again, simplified for brevity
A a = context.A.First()

B b = new B();

// In a roundabout way, they both get a reference to each other
a.B = b;
b.A = a;

context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;

context.SaveChanges();
```

My problem is that once I have done this, and I go back in to the function where this code was executed, object A doesn't have a reference of object B until I trigger a breakpoint and look into `context.B`'s list. The list of class B contains the object which A should point to, but A doesn't have a reference of it until I breakpoint and look in to `context.B` list.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try calling context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() after making the change

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had added `context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;` to replicate that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You pull `A` from the context but I think you need to tell it about the new relationship with B in a way the context understands, eg:

```
context.Bs.Add(b); //context now knows about the new b entity
a.B = b;
context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified; //I think this is needed only of a's scalar properties have changed? but there is no harm in adding it anyway
context.SaveChanges();
```

Setting `a.B=b;` and `context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;` will set any unset entities in a's object graph to Modified - like B - when b really needs to be set as Added. Using `Add()` will do this.

Comment: When you say 'when b really needs to be set as Added', are you referring to it being added to the context, or the entity? If you mean the entity, I don't really understand what that would do, simply because I don't know whether the entity has an 'Add()' function. Second of all, this code adds B to the context perfectly because EF knows the relationship.

Comment: The thing is that the `context.B` is updated when I put the references to the object so it is added without having to explicitly call `Add()`.

Comment: Yes - but I'm not sure the change tracker knows about it. The change tracker only tracks scalar values - to paraphrase Julie Lerman "When you change a foreign key property, such as A.B_Id, the context
is aware of that property. But when you change a navigation property, there’s nothing to track. Even if you mark the 'A' as Modified, the context is only aware of the scalar properties." - but if the code I've posted doesn't work for you then that doesn't really help I know
"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making your `A` and `B` properties `virtual` in your class definition?
Please feedback, I'm not really sure, but that could be the problem.

Comment: I don't want lazy initialisation, so they're not `virtual`